# Get "embedded nul(s) found in input" when reading a csv using read.csv()

Tags: r

I was reading in a csv file.

Code is:

```
mydata = read.csv("mycsv.csv", header=True, sep=",", quote="\"")
```

Get the following warning:

> Warning message:
>   In `scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec`,  :
>     embedded nul(s) found in input

Now some cells in my CSV have missing values that are represented by "".

How do I write this code so that I do not get the above warning?

Comment: Does this opencsv bug report : http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/bugs/96/ : look like it might have led to your CSV file having nulls? If that's not it and you're on a Linux system, `tr -d '\000' < filein > fileout` will remove the nulls, but that might not fully fix your issue.

Comment: MMMmm I'll check ... good find

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your CSV might be encoded in UTF-16. This isn't uncommon when working with some Windows-based tools.

You can try loading a UTF-16 CSV like this:

```
read.csv("mycsv.csv", ..., fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't file it ... I am pretty sure I'm not dealing with a UTF-16LE file

Comment: @user1172468: Have you tried looking at the file in a hexeditor? There might be embedded NULs, I guess. What program generated your CSVs?

Comment: I got the following: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'mycsv.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'mycsv.csv'

Comment: I generated it using opencsv in Java -- I'm pretty confident that there are no utf-16 characters in the file -- but I could always be wrong

Comment: I don't know what is "UTF-16LE", but it helped me!!

Answer (score 41):

You can try using the `skipNul = TRUE` option.

```
mydata = read.csv("mycsv.csv", quote = "\"", skipNul = TRUE)
```

From `?read.csv`

> Embedded nuls in the input stream will terminate the field currently being read, with a warning once per call to scan. Setting `skipNul = TRUE` causes them to be ignored.

It worked for me.

Comment: @Richard, @Apex, or someone, will you please point me to a resource or 1) define an "embedded nul" and 2) explain in more detail what `skipNul = TRUE` does?  Thanks.

Comment: Null is ASCII value `0` (Hx0), called `NUL` or `null` (check any ASCII table).  A (manipulated or converted) string can contain these characters.  Sometime they are rendered as `\0`, as in `ABC\0EFG`. SkipNul = TRUE ignores them.

Comment: @Enzo thanks for the feedback.  I'm inferring R thinks embedded nulls should become `NA`s; however, because the argument for `na.strings = <input>` is unclear or insufficient to convert _all_ embedded nulls to `NA`s, R leaves the remainders as text strings with their source value.  Correct?  If so, is there any way to  determine which data points R ignored as embedded nulls?  (The goal being to convert them to `NA`s.)  Thanks, again.

Comment: In my case (the output from a machine) skipNul was fine.

Comment: But with the output of another machine, I had to use UTF-16LE encoding.

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing to do with the encoding. This is the problem with reading of the nulls in the file. To handle that, you need to pass the `skipNul = TRUE` paramater.

for example:

`neg = scan('F:/Natural_Language_Processing/negative-words.txt', what = 'character', comment.char = '', encoding = "UTF-8", skipNul = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Might be a file that do not have CRLF, might only have LF. Try to check the HEX output of the file.

If so. Try running the file through awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' file > new_log_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and figured out that although my files had a .csv extensions and opened up with no problems in a spreadsheet, they were actually saved as ¨All Formats¨ rather than ¨Text CSV (.csv)¨

Answer (score 1):

Another quick solution:

**Double check that you are, in fact, reading a `.csv` file!**

I was accidentally reading a `.rds` file instead of `.csv` and got this "embedded null" error.

Answer (score 0):

In those cases be sure the data you are importing does not have "#" characters but if that the case try using the option `comment.char=""`. It worked for me.