# Not being able to properly read csv with R

Tags: r, csv

I run the following:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/directory/file.csv")
```

These are my warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In read.table("C:/Users/user/Desktop/directory/file.csv",  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table("C:/Users/user/Desktop/directory/file.csv",  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls

          ....

6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

The resulting data frame is just a column filled with NAs.

A problem might be that all my data is in one column separated by commas like this(first row is header, second row is example data):

```
stat_breed,tran_disp,train_key,t_type,trainer_Id,horsedata_Id
QH,"Tavares Joe","214801","E",0,0
```

What can I do to accurately read my data?

Comment: You can try adding `skipNul = T` to your read.csv call and see if that reads your data in properly

Comment: thank you @CactusWoman. I think skipNul= T and sep = "," did the job

Comment: would you mind explaining me what was happening?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with whatever is producing the data. You should track that down and fix it, ideally, rather than accepting faulty input in R.

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209464/get-embedded-nuls-found-in-input-when-reading-a-csv-using-read-cv) for a discussion of the issue.

Comment: thank you @KonradRudolph. Do you think there might be risks if I use skipNul = T? If so what risks? Unfortunately I don't have too much control on what is generating the data

Comment: @jgozal `skipNul=T` itself probably only carries minimal risks. But you’re receiving garbled data, so the process generating the data is clearly buggy. That should be a huge warning sign. — Do you know that you can actually trust the data?