# What does skipNul = TRUE in read.table() and read.csv() do (beyond skipping/ignoring embedded nulls)?

Tags: r, csv, read.table, read.csv

I realize setting `skipNul = TRUE` in `read.csv()` and `read.table()` skips over/ignores "embedded nulls" (see `?read.csv` and [Get "embedded nul(s) found in input" when reading a csv using read.csv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209464/get-embedded-nuls-found-in-input-when-reading-a-csv-using-read-csv)).

**What does skipping/ignoring embedded nulls mean for the resulting data in R?**  I expect R's "skipping" or "ignoring" them means they're kept as text strings, when they would ideally show up as `NA` values, except the `na.strings` argument wasn't sufficient to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

This is very late but as someone who ran into R's character encoding hell and found documentation sorely lacking: Embedded nuls aren't NAs, they're invisible characters embedded in strings. You don't lose anything from the data by getting rid of them.