# read.csv in R skipping non-standard rows

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a CSV file where the first row is more of a comment (see bottom for illustration) and i would like to ignore it in a read.csv.

using skip=2 for read.csv doesn't work either - wondering if anyone has figured out how this might be done?

Error for using skip message is: 
*Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  empty beginning of file
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(file, skip) : line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls*

My Report (Jan 1, 2016-Aug 27, 2016)

Header A    Header B    Header C

John Dole   20          100

Comment: If the first row is a comment, `skip=1` can be used

Comment: Thank you for responding - Ive tried that but it throw and error where i can't figure out - Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :  empty beginning of file
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(file, skip) : line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul

Comment: Perhaps you need the correct encoding as showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209464/get-embedded-nuls-found-in-input-when-reading-a-csv-using-read-csv)

Comment: Encoding is Unicode- the strange part is if I opened the file in Excel, and manually delete off the first line, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Thanky you! this is a duplicate - I should have Googled harder on the error. My apologies.