# Read tab delimited text file

Tags: r

I am trying to read the data from **[this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission.txt)** link in R using the following code but I keep getting warning messages and the dataframe doesn't read the data properly.

```
url <- 'https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission.txt'
df <- read.table(url, sep = '\t',header = F, skip = 2,quote='', comment='')
```

Can you tell what I need to change to read the data

**EDIT**

Adding data snippet

```
REMISS  CELL    SMEAR   INFIL   LI  BLAST   TEMP
1   0.8 0.83    0.66    1.9 1.1 1
1   0.9 0.36    0.32    1.4 0.74    0.99
0   0.8 0.88    0.7 0.8 0.18    0.98
0   1   0.87    0.87    0.7 1.05    0.99
1   0.9 0.75    0.68    1.3 0.52    0.98
0   1   0.65    0.65    0.6 0.52    0.98
1   0.95    0.97    0.92    1   1.23    0.99
0   0.95    0.87    0.83    1.9 1.35    1.02
```

Comment: The file appears to have many invalid chars. If you copy its contents, you can probably safely read it in as `paste(readClipboard(), collapse="\n")`, though. For example, with the data.table package `data.table::fread(paste(readClipboard(), collapse="\n"))`. Btw, this is not a good question for SO, relying on external links for example data.

Comment: I can't say there are invalid chars. I downloaded the file and tried reading it. I still got the same errors. I then replaced the tabs with commas and read it again by setting `sep = ","` and it worked. Also, I added the url to make it easier for people to directly copy paste and run the code. But yeah, point noted. Thanks

Comment: Re invalid chars, I think ycw's answer works and is the right way; I was suggesting manually selecting the contents, right-click -> copy to get it to the clipboard. This crude workaround worked for me. Btw, the reason for not liking external links is (as you probably know) that we want the Q&A to still be valuable years from now (when most links like that will be broken).

Comment: true that. made ammends

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an issue about encoding. Please see this thread for more information ([Get "embedded nul(s) found in input" when reading a csv using read.csv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209464/get-embedded-nuls-found-in-input-when-reading-a-csv-using-read-csv)).

```
url <- 'https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission.txt'
df <- read.table(url, sep = '\t',header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")
```

Answer (score 3):

Also consider,

```
url <- 'https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission.txt'
df <- read.csv(url, sep="\t", header=T)
```