# Having trouble reading an .csv database

Tags: r, csv, readr

I'm trying to read in a `.csv` file using `readr::read_csv`

```
readr::read_csv("my_file.csv")
```

But I got the following error:

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  col_character()
)
Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_,  : 
  Evaluation error: Column 1 must be named.
```

What is going on exactly?

The `.csv` file can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W_ZetpOfWDuSVhiIVAa0sEcRE4ujCSXB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Gautam Yes, originally I thought the same, but the linked post is about `read.csv` not `readr::read_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the encoding and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23209464/680068) shows how it can be done using `read.csv`:

```
read.csv("BRA_females-45q15.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

To achieve the same using `readr::read_csv` we can do as below, first we can find out the encoding:

```
guess_encoding(file = "BRA_females-45q15.csv")
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   encoding   confidence
#   <chr>           <dbl>
#   1 UTF-16LE         1   
# 2 ISO-8859-1       0.8 
# 3 ISO-8859-2       0.51
```

Then use `read_csv` with *locale*:

```
read_csv("BRA_females-45q15.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"))

# Error in guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale) : 
#   Incomplete multibyte sequence
```

But this again give us an error, and looks like [a know issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/306).

> **Hadley:** "Yeah, this is a big issue that will need some thought. In general, readr currently assumes that it can read byte-by-byte, and anything else will require quite of lot of work/thought."