# R not importing all rows from CSV

Tags: r, file, csv, rstudio

I'm attempting to load a `csv` into a data frame but not getting the same number of rows when executing `nrow` vs `Excel`.

Looking at the max row in R I can see there are `ASCII` control characters in a varchar column when viewing it in Notepad++. For example: CAN, EM, STX, ETC

Is this causing the problem for incomplete load?

I've tried changing the encoding in the data import but this didn't work.

Data import code: 
`claims <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\claims - barbican.csv", sep="\t")`

I'm expecting the row count in R to equal the row count in Excel/Notepad++

Comment: If there are commas in your fields, that will cause problems when reading in the data. Also, is this a CSV or TSV? You have `sep = '\t'` which would be a TSV

Comment: Hi. It's a tab separated file saved as .csv. There are commas in the data which is why I created a tab delimited file in SSIS

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909150/why-cant-r-read-this-csv-file/57909913#57909913

Comment: Besides trying out `data.table::fread` (which has better error reporting) you could try out a tool like [CSVed](https://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) to load and examine the CSV data file for errors...

Comment: Hi. Using fread has worked much better than read.csv. I now have 99% of the rows in RStudio.Annoyingly I'm getting an error saying "Stopped reading at empty line 18815 but text exists afterwards (discarded)". Line 18814 has a CRLF at the end so not sure why the last line is being ignore. Why has fread worked better than read.csv and why is the last line being ignored?